# Problem Visualizing 3D Terrain Model - USGS DEM

Tags: dem, geotiff-tiff, terrain, arcscene

I recently downloaded a GeoTIFF 1 arc second from the USGS National Map Viewer.  I added the raster to ArcScene and attempted to visualize the data in 3D.  I set the Base Height to Floating on a Custon Surface, changed the Resolution to that of the Original Surface (3612 rows and columns; 0.000278 cell size).  However, when it's done processing, my DEM just looks a mess; there are giant spikes all through the data.  I've tried downloading DEMS from other areas and repeating the process but I get the same result.

What am I doing wrong?  I suspect perhaps there are Null values but I'm not sure.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You've got a projection issue. Chances are you've not specified the projection of the DEM correctly.
There are typically two indicators to this and you have both:

- You have spikes.
- You have a cell size that looks like: `0.000278` (it should be a whole number).

So make sure you've set the correct projection for the DEM as well as the drape (if memory serves, the issue is mostly DEM side).

Comment: Yes I believe DEMs from the national map come in lat long coordinates but lack horizontal distance units, therefore reprojecting the DEM should be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan - I projected the data to UTM using the Project Raster tool and still have the same problem so I'm assuming that it must be a problem with the cell size.  Do you know how that can be fixed?  I saw that I can change the cell size when I project the raster but doing this changed the values to 26.81883836 and still created spikes when I set the base height and resolution.

Comment: @Ashley - I don't have ArcScene, its been a few years, but I don't think there's anything wrong with the cell size - that's a symptom of the problem rather than the problem itself. I'd go with edgetti and `reproject` the entire DEM to hopefully resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you both - I got the projection to work.  The problem was that I didn't have the Scene Layer (Data frame) coordinate system matching the newly projected layer. Thanks again for letting me to know to first project the data.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem as you but had a different solution.

In scene properties I changed the "Vertical Exaggeration" to "Geographic"

(i know the question was asked a while ago but this offers another explanation.

(Im using Arc Scene 10.1)